# MQTT Kafka Source connector : funny byte characters

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt, apache-kafka-connect, mosquitto

I am following https://github.com/kaiwaehner/kafka-connect-iot-mqtt-connector-example for connecting Mosquitto and Kafka with MQTT source connector. I am getting the data sent by the Mosquitto Publisher into the Mosquitto Subscriber and the Kafka Consumer. But the key and value field in my ConsumerRecord object of kafka-consumer is having some prepended byte characters.
Below are the code snippets and the outputs I'm getting.

**mqttPublisher.py**

```
while v3 < 3:
             data3 = {
                      "time": str(datetime.datetime.now().time()),
                       "val": v3
                      }
             client.publish("sensor/dist", json.dumps(data3), qos=2)

             v3 += 1
             time.sleep(2)
```

**mqttSubscriber.py**

```
def on_message_print(client, userdata, message):
            print(message.topic,message.payload)

subscribe.callback(on_message_print, "sensor/#", hostname="localhost")
```

**kafkaConsumer.py**

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('mqtt.',
                     bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])

for message in consumer:
   print(message)
```

**Output:mqttSubscriber.py**

sensor/dist b'{"time": "12:44:30.817462", "val": 0}'

sensor/dist b'{"time": "12:44:32.820040", "val": 1}'

sensor/dist b'{"time": "12:44:34.822657", "val": 2}'

**Output : kafkaConsumer.py**

ConsumerRecord(topic='mqtt.', partition=0, offset=225, timestamp=1545117270870, timestamp_type=0, **key=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x16sensor/dist'**, **value=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02J{"time": "12:44:30.817462", "val": 0}**', headers=[('mqtt.message.id', b'0'), ('mqtt.qos', b'0'), ('mqtt.retained', b'false'), ('mqtt.duplicate', b'false')], checksum=None, serialized_key_size=17, serialized_value_size=43, serialized_header_size=62)

ConsumerRecord(topic='mqtt.', partition=0, offset=226, timestamp=1545117272821, timestamp_type=0, **key=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x16sensor/dist'**, **value=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02J{"time": "12:44:32.820040", "val": 1}'**, headers=[('mqtt.message.id', b'0'), ('mqtt.qos', b'0'), ('mqtt.retained', b'false'), ('mqtt.duplicate', b'false')], checksum=None, serialized_key_size=17, serialized_value_size=43, serialized_header_size=62)

ConsumerRecord(topic='mqtt.', partition=0, offset=227, timestamp=1545117274824, timestamp_type=0, **key=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x16sensor/dist'**, **value=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02J{"time": "12:44:34.822657", "val": 2}'**, headers=[('mqtt.message.id', b'0'), ('mqtt.qos', b'0'), ('mqtt.retained', b'false'), ('mqtt.duplicate', b'false')], checksum=None, serialized_key_size=17, serialized_value_size=43, serialized_header_size=62)

What is causing the above prepending of extra bytes in the Kafka Consumer?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the demo, you're starting a Schema Registry

> Start Kafka Connect and dependencies (Kafka, Zookeeper, Schema Registry):
>
> `confluent start connect`

If you look at the first 5 bytes, you'll see they start with 0, then four more bytes representing an integer.

See the [Schema Registry Wire Format](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#wire-format) and try doing a `curl localhost:8081/subjects` to see if it lists your topic name for `mqtt-key` and `mqtt-value`.

If you didn't want Avro, you would need to configure and edit your Kafka Connect property file to use different Converters, and not use `confluent start` other than getting Kafka and Zookeeper running

Or if you want Python to deserialize the Avro, you can refer to the confluent-kafka-python repo on Github